Best choice of functions for approximating Definite Integrals

What are the best choices of functions for estimating Integrals like the following or for finding the upper and lower bounds ?.
Is there a method except for the classic hit and trial with a lot of functions ?.
\begin{align*}
& \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{x}
{\rm d}x,\quad
\int_{1}^{2}\frac{{\rm d}x}{\,\sqrt{\,{2x^{3} - 9x^{2} + 12x + 14}\,}\,},
\\[2mm] & \int_{0}^{1}\left[\frac{\sqrt{x}-1}{\ln\left(x\right)}\right]^{2} {\rm d}x
\end{align*}
For the first one I've tried something like
\begin{align*}
& {\large\because}\ \sin\left(x\right) \leq x
\\[2mm] &
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{x}{\rm d}x \leq \int_{0}^{1}{\rm d}x
\end{align*}
This works for somewhat, since the value of the left hand side is $\approx 0.9460$ and the right hand side is well, $1$.
But the error after keeps on increasing and as a whole, I dont think this is a correct approach at all.
For the other two, I dont even have a place to start.

Some motivation and further reading material  would be appreciated.

The usual methods of numerical integration don't tell you whether they over- or underestimate without additional information such as computing the $n$th derivative of the integrand (generally $n$ is higher for more precise estimators) at one or more points, or at least the sign thereof. If you want to guarantee an upper bound, or guarantee a lower bound, rather than just a close estimate, you're likely to need less precise methods.

If you work with small intervals, series could be a way to use. For the second problem, I should expand around $x=1$. For the third problem, around $x=\frac 32$. Using only two terms, the results would be $0.178819$ (the exact value being $0.169899$) and $0.232543$ (the exact value being $0.232526$)

@ClaudeLeibovici, Indeed. One other approach I tried was perhaps finding the maxima of $f'(x)$ and then putting that as bounds for the integration. In this case, the derivative of the second function is bounded in the interval ($\frac{1}{\sqrt{19}}$,$\frac{1}{\sqrt{18}}$). that gives a neat value of the integration, being in the interval $(0.22941, 0.2357)$. You seem to have used the average right?
